# Facebook custom tab for app

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-iframe, facebook-page, facebook-apps

I developing a facebook app for my university's library, the problem is that I want 5 different tabs in my app and every tab, I have used  command in index.php file but It show command error. I dun know how can I create tabs or menu in my own app. I have found many tutorials regarding adding tabs in facebook page. But i am unable to find any tutorial which guide me how to write code to create tabs in facebook app.

Someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create an app, before you can add it as a tab to a Facebook page.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are some vocabulary / language issues here.  Please clarify.

When you say "tab", do you mean five elements that would create five links to the left side FB menu inside a fanpage

or

do you mean a "menu" of five distinct "screenviews" inside one url that creates one link in the left side menu ?

Both can be done.